# find the maximum Split of Positive Even integers given an array

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to solve LeetCode problem [2178. Maximum Split of Positive Even Integers](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-split-of-positive-even-integers/description/):

> You are given an integer `finalSum`. Split it into a sum of a **maximum** number of **unique** positive even integers.
>
> - For example, given `finalSum = 12`, the following splits are valid (unique positive even integers summing up to `finalSum`): `(12)`, `(2 + 10)`, `(2 + 4 + 6)`, and `(4 + 8)`. Among them, `(2 + 4 + 6)` contains the maximum number of integers. Note that `finalSum` cannot be split into `(2 + 2 + 4 + 4)` as all the numbers should be unique.
>
> Return *a list of integers that represent a valid split containing a maximum number of integers*. If no valid split exists for `finalSum`, return *an **empty** list*. You may return the integers in any order.
>
> #### Constraints:
>
> - 1 <= `finalSum` <= 10<sup>10</sup>

I am trying to do it using for-loops. For instance, I have an the following `arr` and `finalSum` values:

```
even = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16]
finalSum = 16

current_sum = 0
current_comb = []
all_combs = []

for j in range(len(even)):
    
    current_comb.append(even[j])
    
    for k in range(j+1, len(even)):

        current_comb.append(even[k])

        print("current combination", current_comb)

        current_sum = sum(current_comb)
        print("current sum", current_sum)

        if current_sum == finalSum:
            print("sum = finalSum")
            # append to all combs
            all_combs.append(current_comb)
            current_comb = []
            
        elif current_sum > finalSum:
            print("current sum > final sum")
            # since array is sorted by ASC, even other value is going to be >, therefore pop the last 2 elements
            current_comb = current_comb[:-2]
            print("pop last 2 elements", current_comb)
```

I am stuck here and trying to figure out next steps. I prefer solving this using `for` or `while` loops.

Comment: Why don’t you start tackling the problem by removing the word “even”? Then you will spot a MUCH faster solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to to have a nested loop. There is a *greedy* solution to this that is quite straightforward. For even sums there is always a solution where only the last two entries of the returned list might differ by more than 2. All the other ones can be a prefix of 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, ...etc. So you don't need to test for other combinations.

You can just start up filling the result list with 2, 4, 6, ... until you exceed the sum. At that point you need indeed some logic to fix the end of the list so the total is correct.

Some other remarks:

- You don't need to build an `arr` with even numbers. The `range` function can be used to step by 2.
- The input can be odd. In that case there is no solution and you should not spend time on looping

Here is an implementation:

```
class Solution:
    def maximumEvenSplit(self, finalSum: int) -> List[int]:
        res = []
        if finalSum % 2 == 0:  # only even inputs have a solution
            for i in range(2, finalSum + 1, 2):  # step by 2
                res.append(i)  # Greedily append this even number
                finalSum -= i   # Adapt to reflect which value we still need
                if finalSum <= i:  # We are going to exceed the sum...
                    break  # ... so abort...
            res[-1] += finalSum  # ... and fix the last value in the list.
        return res
```

Comment: can you explain this a bit, maybe with an example: "For even sums there is always a solution where only the last two entries of the returned list might differ by more than 2"

Comment: Sure, if you take *any* solution you can convert it to one where all except the last are a prefix of 2, 4, 6, 8, ... etc. For example: 28 has solution [6,8,2,12], but we can decrease the 6 to 4 and compensate that change in the greatest member, so we get [4, 8, 2, 14]. We can do the same with the 8, so we get [4, 6, 2, 16]. Sorting gives [2, 4, 6, 16]. By now you should see you can do this always and convert any solution to this "normalised" one. So that means we can limit our search for a solution that has that pattern.

Comment: how does this ensure that the combination obtained is of max of unique integers?

Comment: Because you will have used the smallest possible integers available. There is no way to reduce any of the non-last members, because they are all taken. The last one cannot be broken into two, as we checked that its half would not be greater than the one-but-last element in the list. So there is no way to get more elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you first divide by 2 you can anticipate the number of terms (N) to ensure that N is the largest integer such that the sum of the first N terms, N(N+1)/2, is less than or equal to finalSum / 2. That amounts to the solution of a quadratic. Only the last item in the list (might) need to be adjusted.

A list comprehension can be used to replace the external for loop.

```
def maximumEvenSplit( finalSum ):
    from math import sqrt
    if finalSum % 2 != 0: return []

    half = finalSum // 2                                   # remove "even" stipulation
    N = int( 0.5 * ( -1.0 + sqrt( 1.0 + 8.0 * half ) ) )   # largest N such that N(N+1)/2 <= half
    extra = half - N * ( N + 1 ) // 2                      # amount by which last is adjusted
    L = [ 2 * i for i in range( 1, N ) ] + [ 2 * ( N + extra ) ]
    return L

for i in [ 12, 7, 28 ]:
    print( i, " ---> ", maximumEvenSplit( i ) )
```

Output:

```
12  --->  [2, 4, 6]
7  --->  []
28  --->  [2, 4, 6, 16]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) from the standard library to get the possible partitions of an integer with *unique* digits.

Starting from the longest combination towards the shortest, iteration break at the 1st match. The iteration space maybe quite big (hence slow execution)!

```
from itertools import combinations


def longest_sum_partition(n):
    for length in range(n, 0, -1):
        for c in combinations(range(2, n+1, 2), length):
            if sum(c) == n:
                return list(c)
    return []


print(longest_sum_partition(3))
#[]
print(longest_sum_partition(12))
# [2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given an input of n (an even number):

1. O(1): Solve k(k+1) = n for k.
2. O(1): Let k' = floor(k)
3. O(k') = O(sqrt(n)): return [2, 4, 6, ..., 2*(k'-1), n - (k'-1)*(k')]

The third step is only slow because of the length of the answer. If you can return it succinctly as the number of consecutive even numbers starting at 2, together with the final entry, then it's also O(1).

Note that 2 + 4 + 6 + ... + 2k = 2*(1+2+3+...+k) = k*(k+1)

Example

```
n = 28
k^2 + k - 28 = 0
k = (-1 + sqrt(1+4*28))/2
k = 4.815...

Now, let k' = floor(k). Here k' = 4.
```

One solution is be [2, 4, ..., 2*(k' - 1), n - (k'-1)*(k')]

Continuing the example, we have [2, 4, 6, 28 - (3*4)] = [2, 4, 6, 16].

Ruby Code:

```rb
def f(n)
  k = ((-1 + (1+4*n)**0.5)/2).to_i
  ans = []
  1.upto(k-1) do |i|
    ans.append(2*i)
  end
  ans.append n - (k-1)*k
  puts "k = #{k}, #{ans.to_s}.sum == #{ans.sum} == #{n}"
end
```

Results

```
1.upto(50) do |i|
  f(2*i)
end
k = 1, [2].sum == 2 == 2
k = 1, [4].sum == 4 == 4
k = 2, [2, 4].sum == 6 == 6
k = 2, [2, 6].sum == 8 == 8
k = 2, [2, 8].sum == 10 == 10
k = 3, [2, 4, 6].sum == 12 == 12
k = 3, [2, 4, 8].sum == 14 == 14
k = 3, [2, 4, 10].sum == 16 == 16
k = 3, [2, 4, 12].sum == 18 == 18
k = 4, [2, 4, 6, 8].sum == 20 == 20
k = 4, [2, 4, 6, 10].sum == 22 == 22
k = 4, [2, 4, 6, 12].sum == 24 == 24
k = 4, [2, 4, 6, 14].sum == 26 == 26
k = 4, [2, 4, 6, 16].sum == 28 == 28
k = 5, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10].sum == 30 == 30
k = 5, [2, 4, 6, 8, 12].sum == 32 == 32
k = 5, [2, 4, 6, 8, 14].sum == 34 == 34
k = 5, [2, 4, 6, 8, 16].sum == 36 == 36
k = 5, [2, 4, 6, 8, 18].sum == 38 == 38
k = 5, [2, 4, 6, 8, 20].sum == 40 == 40
k = 6, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12].sum == 42 == 42
k = 6, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 14].sum == 44 == 44
k = 6, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 16].sum == 46 == 46
k = 6, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 18].sum == 48 == 48
k = 6, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 20].sum == 50 == 50
k = 6, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 22].sum == 52 == 52
k = 6, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 24].sum == 54 == 54
k = 7, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14].sum == 56 == 56
k = 7, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 16].sum == 58 == 58
k = 7, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 18].sum == 60 == 60
k = 7, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20].sum == 62 == 62
k = 7, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 22].sum == 64 == 64
k = 7, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 24].sum == 66 == 66
k = 7, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 26].sum == 68 == 68
k = 7, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 28].sum == 70 == 70
k = 8, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16].sum == 72 == 72
k = 8, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 18].sum == 74 == 74
k = 8, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 20].sum == 76 == 76
k = 8, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 22].sum == 78 == 78
k = 8, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 24].sum == 80 == 80
k = 8, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 26].sum == 82 == 82
k = 8, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 28].sum == 84 == 84
k = 8, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 30].sum == 86 == 86
k = 8, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 32].sum == 88 == 88
k = 9, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18].sum == 90 == 90
k = 9, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 20].sum == 92 == 92
k = 9, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 22].sum == 94 == 94
k = 9, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 24].sum == 96 == 96
k = 9, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 26].sum == 98 == 98
k = 9, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 28].sum == 100 == 100
```